# Is play! Framework 2.0 suitable for creating a REST API?

Tags: java, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have developed a REST API using Play! Framework 1.2.4, and I have a strong liking for the framework. The simplicity and the rapid development cycle helped me achieve this in a fraction of the time I would have taken had I gone the traditional Java EE route.

Now that I am exploring using Play! 2.0.3 for my next project. I see that while the framework has been enhanced and makes it even easier to develop **web-apps**, the same cannot be said about **REST API's**. My app will not have any HTML whatsoever - I will just respond with XML or JSON or whatever data exchange format I decide to use in future.

So, the question is:

> **Has anyone here used Play 2.0.x for exposing non-html pure REST API's?**

### More Details:

Here are some of the factors I feel make it more difficult to develop pure REST API's in Play 2.0.x compared to 1.2.x. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

#### Content Negotiation is harder

In play! 1.2.4, I content negotiation was build in to the framework. There were options to define right in the routes file what content-type a request expects.

`GET    /friends    User.listFriends(format:'xml')`

Then, in the controller,

```
public static void getFriends(){
    render();
}
```

This would result in the `views/xml/User/listFriends.xml` template being rendered automatically. To add support for JSON tomorrow, all I needed to do was to add a `views/json/User/listFriends.json` template.

I do not see how this can be done in play! 2.0.x

#### Creating non-html templates is less intuitive

After some trial and error, I figured out that one can create, for example, a listFriends.scala.xml in the views folder in play! 2.0. Then, it needs to be invoked in the controller code as follows:

`return ok(views.xml.listFriends.render())`;

However, Eclipse doesn't like this, because Eclipse does not know about the `views.xml.listFriends` since it is generated only after play compilation completes. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Just a side question, how do you render the ui without html? Are you just not writing `.html` files explicitly but making xml templates that have html tags embedded, and then those get rendered into html?

Comment: @Knownasilya No. My app just doesn't have web page UI. The clients for my REST API are smart phone apps (Android, iOS)  - which fetch the data in a RESTful fashion and then display them in a native app as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Play (Scala) you can do something like this:

```
val myXMl = obtainXML();
return Ok(myXML).as("text/xml")
```

I'm not sure of the syntax in Java, but it would be equivalent: instead of creating a template, you generate the XML and then you send it to the user, setting the return type to "text/xml" (or json or whatever you need it to be).

Comment: yes - this [is an option](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaXmlRequests). However, the whole point of a templating engine is defeated :-). Generating my XML is non-trivial as you would imagine in a REST API the response would be large and dynamic. I could use XML/JSON serialization/parsing libs like simple-xml/GSON but the templating engine provides advantages like being able to include one template in another (at least the old grrovy based one does). Believe me - thats a huge plus.

Comment: as far s I understand you can still create your template, and return XML. Is not like the template compiler checks if your HTML is valid... replace the myXML to the path to your template.

Comment: Ah ok! I didn't realize that the template extension was not tied in any way to the content (maybe I was still thinking in terms of play 1.2.4). I will experiment with this. What about content negotiation?

Answer (score 5):

As Pere Villega explained, but with the Java syntax:

```
String xml = getXMLAsString();
return ok(xml).as("text/xml");
```

The [as() method](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/mvc/Results.Status.html#as%28java.lang.String%29) is part of the [Status class](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/index.html).

Or, an alternative is:

```
String xml = getXMLAsString();
response().setContentType("text/xml")
return ok(xml);
```